# How to get statements for IMethodSymbol?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, codefixprovider

I'm working on the Code Fix provider for .Net.

I'd like to check method internals, e.g. method statements from IMethodSymbol.

As an example, I have following code on input:

```
public void DoSomething(string input)
{
    if(input == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("!!!!");
}
```

On the code-fix side I have [IMethodSymbol](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IMethodSymbol.cs.html) interface, and there are not ability to get method statements, internal nodes, etc. (I'd like to see 'if', condition into the 'if', exception raising, etc).

How can I get it?

Comment: When you mention that "On the code-fix side I have IMethodSymbol interface", how did you end up with this method symbol ? Don't you have any underlying syntax nodes (such as a [MethodDeclarationSyntax](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/MethodDeclarationSyntax.cs) from which you could get the method statements nodes from ?

Comment: @PhilGref In my case, I need to register for the semantic node so that I can identify whether the method is ultimately overriding a specific method of a specific type. Then if it is, I need to parse the syntax of the body and see how one of the parameters is treated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property to get the syntax tree defining the method.

Partial methods will have two nodes.

Methods defined in metadata (referenced assemblies) won't have any.

Comment: How do you get the MethodDeclarationSyntax defining the method from the SyntaxReference?